# How do I dynamically update a bootstrap progress bar with data from my PHP script?

Tags: php, css, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap progress bar on my webpage

```
 <div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="70"
  aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:70%">
70%
  </div>
</div>
```

My php script -

```
<?php
function get_memory() {
    foreach(file('/proc/meminfo') as $ri)
        $m[strtok($ri, ':')] = strtok('');
    return 100 - round(($m['MemFree'] + $m['Buffers'] + $m['Cached']) / $m['MemTotal'] * 100);
}
echo "".get_memory()."";
?>
```

When the php function is called, a numeric value is called, which updates.

Essentially, what I want to do, is

```
<?php echo "".get_memory()."";?>
```

on the style="width:70%" of the progress bar, so the progress bar would dynamically update, using the value reported from the php function.

I hope that makes sense.

I have tried

```
<script>
    setInterval(function(){
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: "ramUsage.php",
            success: function(result) {
                $('.progress-bar').css("width", data + '%');
            },
        });
    }, 1000);
</script>
```

This gives me

```
ReferenceError: data is not defined
```

Wouldn't it be better to use websockets instead of AJAX? If so, how would I do that?

Comment: Replace `data` with `result`.  Or vice versa.

Comment: @Teddy Thank you!

Answer (score -2):

Instead of ,

```
 $('.progress-bar').css("width", data + '%');
```

You should have to used ,

```
$('.progress-bar').css("width", result + '%');
```

or

```
$('.progress-bar').css("width", result.responseText + '%');
```